# Java 8 stream: parse list of maps

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to get list of Long from list of maps using Stream API.

This is how class looks like:

```
class Report Bean{
   private MarshallableMap data;
}
```

Object data contains records like this: ("ID", 1), ("Name", "TestName").

I need to get list of IDs from list of ReportBeans. 
This is what I've tried:

```
 List<Long> ids = reportBeans.stream().flatMap(
                    m -> m.getData().entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals("ID"))
                            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                            .map(Long.class::cast))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I am getting empty list. Please, I need advice. Thank you

Comment: are you sure there are any beans with a key that is exactly `"ID"`?

Comment: Do share what `MarshallableMap` consists of. How is `ID` related. And maybe a typo in class name `ReportBean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot of unnecessary streaming going on. I think this is more suited for your needs:

```
reportBeans.stream()
  .map(r -> r.getData().get("ID"))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(Long.class:cast)
  .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how your class 'MarshallableMap' looks like. It is necessary for us to provide an exact answer. But if your 'data' field is of type `Map<String, String>`, you can get the list of IDs the following way:

```
     List<Long> ids = reportBeans.stream()
        .flatMap(
                m -> (m.getData().entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(e -> "ID".equals(e.getKey()))
                        .map(e -> Long.valueOf(e.getValue())))
        )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why do you people insist on iterating over `entrySet`?

Comment: @MikhailProkhorov, who's insisting that? My answer just provides a fix in OP's code with minimal changes. There are always ways to improve a program which is off topic here.